# fail2ban Service Crashing

Tags: ssh, fail2ban

I have a miss behaving fail2ban service on a very much live server.
It'll tally up to 100% cpu usage after boot for about 30min then goes down to a stable 0.1%
It freakin me out, something is crashing the server and now I have to migrate.

LOG

```
2011-09-26 09:02:45,921 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Added logfile = /var/log/auth.log
2011-09-26 09:02:45,922 fail2ban.server : ERROR  Unexpected communication error
2011-09-26 09:02:45,922 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set maxRetry = 6
2011-09-26 09:02:45,923 fail2ban.server : ERROR  Unexpected communication error
2011-09-26 09:02:45,923 fail2ban.server : ERROR  Unexpected communication error
2011-09-26 09:02:45,924 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set findtime = 600
2011-09-26 09:02:45,924 fail2ban.server : ERROR  Unexpected communication error
2011-09-26 09:02:45,924 fail2ban.actions: INFO   Set banTime = 600
2011-09-26 09:02:45,925 fail2ban.server : ERROR  Unexpected communication error
2011-09-26 09:02:45,929 fail2ban.server : ERROR  Unexpected communication error
2011-09-26 09:02:45,933 fail2ban.server : ERROR  Unexpected communication error
2011-09-26 09:02:45,939 fail2ban.server : ERROR  Unexpected communication error
2011-09-26 09:02:45,944 fail2ban.server : ERROR  Unexpected communication error
2011-09-26 09:02:45,951 fail2ban.server : ERROR  Unexpected communication error
2011-09-26 09:02:45,959 fail2ban.server : ERROR  Unexpected communication error
2011-09-26 09:02:46,014 fail2ban.server : ERROR  Unexpected communication error
2011-09-26 09:02:46,014 fail2ban.server : ERROR  Unexpected communication error
2011-09-26 09:02:46,015 fail2ban.server : ERROR  Unexpected communication error
2011-09-26 09:02:46,016 fail2ban.server : ERROR  Unexpected communication error
2011-09-26 09:02:46,017 fail2ban.server : ERROR  Unexpected communication error
2011-09-26 09:02:46,017 fail2ban.server : ERROR  Unexpected communication error
2011-09-26 09:02:46,018 fail2ban.server : ERROR  Unexpected communication error
2011-09-26 09:02:46,019 fail2ban.server : ERROR  Unexpected communication error
2011-09-26 09:02:46,019 fail2ban.server : ERROR  Unexpected communication error
2011-09-26 09:02:46,035 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh' started
2011-09-26 09:02:46,043 fail2ban.server : ERROR  Unexpected communication error
2011-09-26 09:13:48,352 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Ban 114.135.11.187
```

Unexpected communication error looks like it can't communicate with its sock, anyone agree?

Thanks 
Kyle

Comment: Which version are you running?

Comment: 0.83v i think, on ubuntu

Comment: Could you please show us the output of `python -V`?

Comment: # python -V
Python 2.6.2

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it looks like it cannot connect to it's socket.

Can you unjail it:

```
2011-09-26 09:02:46,035 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh' started
```

The chroot may be interfering with its ability to find things it needs.